# Monday's Bee Donimoes Problem

Tags: dominoes

A swarm of dice bring nectar back to the hive from a domino garden. I just
finished adding a new puzzle race game to [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/), my collection of domino
puzzles and games, so I thought I would post a few bonus problems here. The game
is Bee Donimoes, and the bees are dice flying back to the queen bee. Each die
has to stay on the numbers that match it.

#### Equipment

- a set of dominoes from double blank to double six
- 4 six-sided dice

#### Object

Bring the nectar back to the hive in as few moves as possible. The biggest die
is the queen bee and doesn't move, the others have to form a connected group
around her.

#### Setup

Each problem has a diagram of the dominoes, so lay out the dominoes to match it.
Look for the dominoes with a number at one end and a blank at the other. The
number on each of those dominoes is the starting space for the die with the
matching number. Take 3 dice, turn them so the numbers 1, 2, and 3 are on top,
then place them on their starting spaces.

Here's an example setup with the dice added:

[image: setup]

#### Play

The die with the largest number is the queen bee, which never moves during the
round. All the smaller bees have to bring their nectar back to her in one
connected group. (Diagonal connections don't count.)

The dice can only land on their own numbers. They can move in two ways:

1. In a straight line along a row or a column. They can pass over other numbers,
   squares with their own number, or other dice. This counts as one move.
2. Changing direction over other dice. In the middle of a regular move, a die
   may make a 90° turn directly above another die. Later in the same move, it
   may make more turns directly above other dice. No matter how many turns it
   makes, this still counts as one move.

The blank on the other end of the queen bee's domino is wild. Any die can land
there, if it's empty. A die may also leave the wild space on a later move.

#### Example Solution

Let's solve the set up above, where the 3 die is the queen bee. It seems best to
start by moving the 2 where it can guide the 1 onto the wild spot:

[image: Step 1]

With the 2 in place, the 1 can get to its target.

[image: Step 2]

Finally, the 2 can complete the connected group with the help of the 1, in a
nice leapfrog pattern.

[image: Step 3]

To describe each move, use the number of a die, a direction, and a distance,
then add more directions and distances if the die turns corners. For example,
1R3 means move the 1 die to the right, 3 spaces. The solution above would be:
2D1, 1D3L3, 2L3U1.

#### Next Round

Put the dice back on their starting spaces. If there are any empty starting
spaces, start the next round by adding the next bigger die on its starting
space.

### Today's Problem

Here's a problem to solve for today. Try to solve it in the fewest possible
moves, and post your solution. The solution will include two rounds: three dice
and four dice.

[image: Monday problem]

If you like this puzzle, watch for more challenging problems later in the week.

Comment: We need to both place the dice in starting positions, and then move them around for minimum moves?

Comment: That's correct, @bobble. The dice start in their starting positions, then move to form a connected group with the queen bee. The queen bee never moves.

Comment: @bobble The starting spaces are explained in the **Setup** section (I missed it on my first read-through)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image Legend: White is a die location, Red is an unoccupied starting square, Blue is the wild space.

First round: (9 moves)

> 1 moves to activate 2: 1U3-R1D1-L3-U2-L1
>  Leapfrog: 2L2D4, 1D4R3, 2R3U2, 1U3
>  [image]

Second round: (9 moves)

> 3 gets in position to activate 1: 3L4-D1-R5
>  3 gets in position to activate 2: 1R2-U2L1, 3L5
>  Gathering: 1L4U2, 2L2D4, 1D3
>  [image]