# Wednesday's Bee Donimoes Problem

Tags: dominoes

A swarm of dice bring nectar back to the hive from a domino garden. I just
finished adding a new puzzle race game to [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/), my collection of domino
puzzles and games, so I thought I would post a few bonus problems here. The game
is Bee Donimoes, and the bees are dice flying back to the queen bee. Each die
has to stay on the numbers that match it.

See [Monday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/107970/38) problem for complete rules and and an example solution.

Today's problem is a little bigger and a little more challenging. Good luck, and
post your solution as an answer. The solution will include three rounds: three
dice, four dice, and five dice.

[image: Wednesday problem]

If you like this puzzle, watch for a more challenging problem on Friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First round (9 moves):

> 2 frees 1: 2L5-U1R3-U2-L1-U2-R2
>  Leapfrog: 1L2D4, 2D4L4D1, 1L4D1R1
>  [image]

Second round (<s>12</s> **10** moves):

> 2 frees 1, now with 3: 2U2-L4-U1R1-U2-R2, 3U3-R4
>  Leapfrog: 1L2D1L3, 2D1L3D1R1, 3L3D1R1D1
>  [image]

Third round (<s>7</s> **6** moves):

> 4 helps 3 help 2: 4L1, 3U2R5, 2U3L2
>  Gathering: 4R3U2, 1L3D1, 3L2U1R1
>  [image]