# Friday's Bee Donimoes Problem

Tags: dominoes

A swarm of dice bring nectar back to the hive from a domino garden. I just
finished adding a new puzzle race game to [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/), my collection of domino
puzzles and games, so I thought I would post a few bonus problems here. The game
is Bee Donimoes, and the bees are dice flying back to the queen bee. Each die
has to stay on the numbers that match it.

See [Monday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/107970/38) problem for complete rules and an example solution.

Today's problem is even bigger and more challenging than [Wednesday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/108031/38), it uses
the complete set of double-six dominoes. Good luck, and post your solution as an
answer. The solution will include four rounds: three dice, four dice, five dice,
and six dice.

[image: Friday problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew!

First round (<s>11</s> **10** moves):

> 1 frees 2: 1L4-D1-R1
>  Around and around and around they go: 1U4R4, 2R4D3, 1D3L5, 2L5U2, 1U2R3
>  Cleanup: 2R3D4L1, 1D4R1
>  [image]

Second round (<s>13</s> **11** moves):

> Second verse, same as the first: 1L4-D1-R1-U4R4, 2R4D3, 1D3L5, 2L5U2, 1U2R3
>  but now 3 is mobile: 3U4L3U2R1, 1L3U2L1, 2U2R1D1
>  [image]

Third round (6 moves):

> A simple setup: 1L4, 4D4R1, 2D3L1U1
>  and a simple execution: 2R3, 3U3L2, 2L3
>  [image]

Fourth round (5 moves):

> 1D2, 3R1U5L2, 5U4, 4R2D1R1, 1U5R1
>  [image]